# UNIX Shell Script: List all files and directory in each filesystem including size

Tags: bash, performance, shell, unix

I want to list all files and directory for each filesystem in a unix and save the output into a file. My script is working correctly, but this performance is not very well.

This is the part of script:

```
for fs in $(df -h | awk -F"%" '{print $2}' | sed '1,2d')
do
    for i in $(du -a ${fs} | sort -hr | awk -F" " '{print $2";"$1}')
    do
     if [ -d $(echo ${i} | awk -F";" '{print $1}') ]
     then
      echo -e "FileSystem:"${fs}";Dir:"$(echo ${i} | awk -F";" '{print $1}')";Size:"$(echo ${i} | awk -F";" '{print $2}') >> dirSize.log
     else
      echo -e "FileSystem:"${fs}";File:"$(echo ${i} | awk -F";" '{print $1}')";Size:"$(echo ${i} | awk -F";" '{print $2}') >> fileSize.log
     fi
    done

grep "FileSystem:"${fs}";" fileSize.log | sed -n 1,10p >> top10FilebySize.log

done
```

I need help whit this script performance because it's consuming so much CPU.

Comment: Your script isn't the issue.  You're running du on every single filesystem, and that's expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so, about the performance of the script, exists any form more efficient to do this ?

Comment: From the question statement, it doesn't seem like `du` is necessary.  Just do a recursive ls (find/stat, or find | xargs ls)

Comment: Python would be more efficient, because it would avoid spawning thousands (millions) of processes, and repeatedly closing and opening the log file.